# background detection having font with same color as background

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection, feature-detection

I have image as following (so, this is white figure on red background. This figure have two thin red lines inside it)

[image: in_image]

and I want to receive following image (remove red background but not two red lines inside figure)

[image]

I was trying convexHull from OpenCV, but, obviously that approach works only on convex figures. My feeling that convolution may help here, but have no real idea yet.

Answer (score 1):

Dilate and Erode should work for your example:

```
Mat image = imread("image1.jpg");   

int erosion_size = 5;
int dilation_size = 6;

int threshold_value = 200;

Mat mask;
cvtColor( image, mask, CV_BGR2GRAY );

//BINARY THRESHOLDING
threshold( mask, mask, threshold_value, 255, 0);

Mat erosion_element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size( 2*erosion_size + 1, 2*erosion_size+1 ), Point( erosion_size, erosion_size ) );

Mat dilation_element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size( 2*dilation_size + 1, 2*dilation_size+1 ), Point( dilation_size, dilation_size ) );

dilate(mask, mask, erosion_element);
erode(mask, mask, dilation_element);

Mat target;
image.copyTo(target, mask);

imshow("hello",target);

waitKey();
```

OutPut:

[image: ouput example]

Answer (score 0):

suggestions: :)

- just [floodfill()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill)
- convexHull does what the name says, but has a companion, [convexitydefects](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexitydefects)

Comment: berak, flood fill by black color from (0,0) point will flood also red lines by black :) Notice, those red lines not separated by any pixel from background on left side of figure.

Comment: ah ok. sorry. got it totally backwards. should i just delete it ?

Comment: np, you can leave it for history :) anyway, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

he-he, it looks like convolution with circle having diameter slightly bigger  (8 pixels, for example) than line thickness works!
so, algorithm will looks as following:

1. convolve with circle having diameter slightly bigger than line
   thickness
2. normalize convolution, you are interested in values
   greater than 0.95-0.97
3. for each point on convolution function
   (with values greater than 0.95-0.97) you should zero all
   neighborhoods which are in range R=diameter/2